# Why does the Visual Studio 2017 installer quit when trying to make a offline installer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, failed-installation

I'm using the following command to create an offline installer for Visual Studio 2017 Professional:

> vs_professional.exe --layout c:\vs2017\ --lang en-US

It starts up the initial window but finishes within a few minutes without downloading anything. It creates the folder but only the certificates are in the folder.

Looking at the installation files in the temp directory I was able to find the following lines in dd_vs_professional_decompression_log:

```
[3/9/2017, 13:18:56] The entire Box execution exiting with result code: 0x0
[3/9/2017, 13:18:56] Launched extracted application exiting with result code: 0x57
```

And this in the dd_bootstrapper log

```
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:3/9/2017 1:26:14 PM: Unable to parse the json file since it not exists: 0
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:3/9/2017 1:18:46 PM: Waiting for setup process to complete...
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:3/9/2017 1:18:46 PM: Vs setup process exited with code 87
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:3/9/2017 1:18:55 PM: Bootstrapper Successfully completed.
```

Setup never seems to display the command window that downloads the individual components.

Comment: I got the same error message, but it seems to be related to specifying that optional and/or recommended components should be included. See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/40055/error-when-creating-an-offline-installer-if-recomm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 0x57 (87) means `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`

You need to use:

> vs_professional.exe --layout c:\vs2017 --lang en-US

Apparently the first portion of the installer handles a trailing slash correctly, however the second portion (the one that actually downloads the components) will fail if the directory contains a trailing back slash.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error, but it's solved after re-downloading the vs_professional.exe, later i understand that the file " vs_professional.exe " which located in the installation folder isn't the same as the source file..

try to download the file again and use the command with it and it will work

regards,